# Django: ID Null after Save

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I Got this Models in models.py:

```
class Boats(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
       managed = True
       db_table = 'boats'
       ordering = ['name']

class Clients(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
       managed = True
       db_table = 'clients'
       ordering = ['name']
```

==========================

In the views.py; my function do it like that:

```
  f = NewBoatForm(request.POST)
  if f.is_valid():
        nBoat = f.save()
        print 'ID:'+str(nBoat.id)
        cBoat = ClientsBoats()
        cBoat.client = client
        cBoat.boat = nBoat
        cBoat.save()
```

But django fails with this error:

```
       ValueError: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'boat'.
```

I print the ID but it's Null. Can someOne help me.

Comment: OTOH, I think you could simply use a many-to-many relationship instead of setting up a separate model `ClientsBoats`.

Comment: No, the relationship works fine. All because of Models ID. Thanks Anyway

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've overridden the primary key field, `id`, to be something other than an AutoField. Don't do that.

Normally you wouldn't define it at all, and let Django do it automatically. If you are really really sure that a standard integer field is not big enough, you can use BigAutoField. But I doubt you will have more than 2147483647 boats in your database.